# how to fix multiple codes which throws one error?

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

i've created react app multiple times
downloaded react-beautiful-dnd

wrote code:
`

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DragDropContext>
        <Droppable droppableId='thing'>
          {(provided) => {
            <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps} >
              <Draggable draggableId={0} index={0}>
                {(provided) => {
                  <div {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                    some
                  </div>
                }}
              </Draggable>
              <Draggable draggableId={0} index={0}>
                {(provided) => {
                  <div {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                    thing
                  </div>
                }}
              </Draggable>
            </div>
          }}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`
and seen that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHdOA.png);

i've updated npm demoted npm downloaded yarn

created in every new app and downloaded dnd

it appears when i add Droppable

Do you see why ?

what could be a solution ?

Comment: the same index is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. This is because the styled-components library has changed how it handles ref/innerRef. See their documentation: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs which states: "Using an older version of styled-components (below 4.0.0) or of React? Use the innerRef prop instead."

The tutorial uses v3.2.6, check the package.json here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/eggheadio-projects/react-beautiful-dnd-task-app/tree/lesson-3/?hidenavigation=1

So to fix the error, when using the latest version of style-components (5.3.0), change: innerRef={provided.innerRef} to ref={provided.innerRef}.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood you.
i've used ref instead of innerRef.
And in 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/eggheadio-projects/react-beautiful-dnd-task-app/tree/lesson-3/?hidenavigation=1
in import it's breaks in my code it's brokes in adding to code droppable